# clang static analysis on legacy Windows codebase

Tags: c++, windows, clang

Good day all.

I am looking into getting our (legacy Windows C++) code analyzed by clang.
My very first attempt looks like this:

```
clang++ %1 --analyze -ferror-limit=20 -std=c++14 -I %VCINCLUDE% -I %PLATFORM_HEADERS% -fsyntax-only -Werror -Wmicrosoft -Wno-invalid-token-paste -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -fms-extensions -fdelayed-template-parsing -fms-compatibility -D_ATL_NO_HOSTING -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -DDEBUG
```

I am getting a lot of errors of this kind:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h:414:9: error: unknown type name '_NullNull_terminated_'
typedef _NullNull_terminated_ WCHAR *PZZWSTR;
```

Or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\winnt.h:416:48: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
typedef _NullNull_terminated_ WCHAR UNALIGNED *PUZZWSTR;
```

Is there a way around this? I am not trying to build our product, just to run the clang analyzer.

Comment: `_NullNull_terminated_` is a SAL annotation that should've been replaced with empty space when macro expanded. Is there supposed to be a space after `-I`?

Comment: @VTT - yes, there is a space. But clang finds the path no problem..

Comment: I was missing one of the include paths.